# Cocos2d - CCLabelAtlas - asset is nullptr (android)

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, assets, nullptr

when I do :

```
auto label = CCLabelAtlas::create(StringUtils::toString(speed).c_str(), "arial_image.bmp");
```

I get :

```
09-17 08:37:40.856: D/CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp(1563): relative path = arial_image.bmp
09-17 08:37:40.856: D/CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp(1563): relative path = 
09-17 08:37:40.856: D/CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp(1563): asset is nullptr
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

It seems that there is something wrong with the assets handling in "CCFileUtilsAndroid"

Thanks a lot

Comment: bmp? Are you trying to use Windows' bitmap format? Is that even supported?  I doubt that, it's definitely not going to work on iOS. The default image format for mobile devices is PNG.

Comment: This is a test app for android devices.And by the way, I've already tried to use a .png file. Thanks